# RegEx in grep statement

Tags: regex, grep

I've used this RegEx-tester to check that my RegEx works: http://regex101.com/

```
The RegEx I'm using is: \s?(?<='username' => ').*[^']
The string I'm looking at is: 'username' => 'test12345'
The substring I want to get is: test12345
```

When I enter the RegEx in the RegEx-tester, it shows that the substring gets catched.

Now I want to use the RegEx to grep the substring from a file. So far I had no luck with this statement:

```
grep "\s?(?<='username' => ').*[^']" ./file_to_search
```

grep throws no error. It simply doesn't give a result as it would when no match is found.

I've experimented with escaping the apostrophes in the grep-statement with backslashes, but to no avail.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note you were using `.*[^']` whereas you needed `[^']*`, meaning: a set of characters until `'` is found. Your attempt was saying: a set of characters and then a character not being `'`... which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the lookbehind to work , you need to enable `-P` perl-regexp parameter and also you need to enable `-o` only-matching parameter on grep to print only the match instead of printing the whole line.

```
grep -oP "\s?(?<='username' => ')[^']*" file
```

OR

```
grep -oP "'username' => '\K[^']*" file
```

Comment: It works! I humbly bow to you and your knowledge of grep, RegEx and all of its creations...